# If, else return else value even when the condition is true, inside a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

Here is the function i defined:

```
def count_longest(field, data):
    l = len(field)
    count = 0
    final  = 0
    n = len(data)
    for i in range(n):
        count = 0
        if data[i:i + l] is field:
            while data[i - l: i] == data[i:i + l]:
                count = count + 1
                i = i + 1
        else:
            print("OK")
        if final == 0 or count >= final:
            final = count
    return final

a = input("Enter the field - ")
b = input("Enter the data - ")
print(count_longest(a, b))
```

It works in some cases and gives incorrect output in most cases. I checked by printing the strings being compared, and even after matching the requirement, the loop results in `"OK"` which is to be printed when the condition is not true! I don't get it! Taking the simplest example, if i enter `'as'`, when prompted for field, and `'asdf'`, when prompted for data, i should get `count = 1`, as the longest iteration of the substring `'as'` is once in the string `'asdf'`. But i still get final as `0` at the end of the program. I added the `else` statement just to check the `if` the condition was being satisfied, but the program printed `'OK'`, therefore informing that the if condition has not been satisfied. While in the beginning itself, `data[0 : 0 + 2]` is equal to `'as'`, 2 being length of the `"field"`.

Comment: probably you want to say `in field`? for the if statement

Comment: [Visualize your code executing](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit).  If you are using and IDE now is the time to learn how to use its debugging features. The [pdb module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) can also be helpful. Another useful tactic is to go through your code *by hand* executing it line by line as if you are the interpreter - use a pencil and paper to keep track of variables and conditions. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things I notice when looking at your code.

First, use `==` rather than `is` to test for equality.  The `is` operator checks if the left and right are referring to the very same object, whereas you want to properly compare them.

The following code shows that even numerical results that are equal might not be one and the same Python object:

```py
print(2 ** 31 is 2 ** 30 + 2 ** 30)   # <- False
print(2 ** 31 == 2 ** 30 + 2 ** 30)   # <- True
```

(note: the first expression could either be `False` or `True`—depending on your Python interpreter).

Second, the `while`-loop looks rather suspicious.  If you know you have found your sequence `"as"` at position *i*, you are repeating the `while`-loop as long as it is the same as in position *i*-1—which is probably something else, though.  So, a better way to do the `while`-loop might be like so:

```py
while data[i: i + l] == field:
    count = count + 1
    i = i + l         # <- increase by l (length of field) !
```

Finally, something that might be surprising: changing the variable `i` inside the while-loop has no effect on the for-loop.  That is, in the following example, the output will still be `0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 9`, although it looks like it should skip every other element.

```py
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

It does not effect the outcome of the function, but when debugging you might observe that the function seems to go backward after having found a run and go through parts of it again, resulting in additional `"OK"`s printed out.

**UPDATE:**  Here is the complete function according to my remarks above:

```py
def count_longest(field, data):
    l = len(field)
    count = 0
    final = 0
    n = len(data)
    for i in range(n):
        count = 0
        while data[i: i + l] == field:
            count = count + 1
            i = i + l
        if count >= final:
            final = count
    return final
```

Note that I made two additional simplifications.  With my changes, you end up with an `if` and `while` that share the same condition, i.e:

```py
if data[i:i+1] == field:
    while data[i:i+1] == field:
        ...
```

In that case, the `if` is superfluous since it is already included in the condition of `while`.

Secondly, the condition `if final == 0 or count >= final:` can be simplified to just `if count >= final:`.

Comment: That while loop is unnecessary - the for loop is iterating one index at a time: if the condition is satisfied *add one*. And `count = 0` needs to be removed from the for loop.

Comment: @wwii Actually, I do not think that the while loop is unnecessary.  We are talking about two different problems here.  As I understand the intent of the original code is to get the longest uninterrupted run of a "symbol".  Your suggestion, OTH, would simply count the number of symbol occurrences.

Comment: .. I misunderstood then

Comment: @Tobias, well actually, what i am trying to do is counting the longest continuous iteration of a sub-string in a given string. for example, if i enter 'as' as the field, and type 'asdfrgasasasasfgthdasasas' the function should return 4, but your suggestion made it return 1. And it obviously should, as when i = 0, as = field, but as i turn 1, sd is not equal to field 'as'. Now that you get my problem, what i don't get is, why won't the if statement work properly?? i also changed 'is' to '=='

Comment: @Musical_Ant: The code works perfectly when I try it on my machine.  But just to make sure, I have added the complete function.  And the "continuous iteration of a sub-string" is also known as a "run"; so, I think I did understand correctly what you want to do :-).

Comment: @Tobias Yes, it works! I had a minor error in another part of my program. Thank you very much!